# Magnetic field of a charged cloud

Tags: electromagnetism, thought-experiment

Assume a perfectly insulated hollow sphere containing a gas of particles that has a temperature $T$, where each particle has a charge $q$.

As T changes, will the magnetic field around the sphere change? How could an outside observer tell if the gas had a high or low temperature?

Comment: To produce a magnetic field we need electric currents. How do you think, what currents flow in a charged cloud, how are they directed?

Comment: The electric currents would come frome the charged particles bouncing around in the container, each of them producing their own magnetic field. All the currents have random directions, so the the net-magnetic field should be zero, right? But I could also imagine that as T becomes very high, the magnetic field will start to look like it's fluxuating. But other than that, there'd be no way to tell from the outside? Sorry for the long comment.